# What's the algorithm that Unity is used to measure the influence in 2d blend tree?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any public algorithm? I'm going to fill various properties of blend tree exactly according to this algorithm.

[image]
The size of the blue circles represent influence of responding  motions. How does Unity decide them?